# Why did the float is not working for the inner div after I set relative, absolute position for them?

Tags: html, css, css-position

```
<style>
    div#Header{ height:100px ;background-color: #003333;position: relative;} 
    div#LoginBox {float : right;background-color: palegreen;position: absolute }
</style>

<div id="Header" background="bg_img/header.jpg"> 
    <div id="LoginBox">
        <form action="CheckLoginCredentials" method="post">
            <table style="height : 50px">
                <th align="left">
                    LOGIN
                </th>
                <tr>
                    <td> Username :</td>
                    <td>Password :</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="uname"  ></td>
                    <td><input type="password" name="pwd" /></td>
                    <td><input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"></td>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" colspan="2">
                        Not Registered? Register <a href="RegistrationPage.jsp" style="text-decoration: none "> Here</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: what is the expected behavior?

Comment: there is a </tr> missing after the submit button

Answer (score 1):

You must use:

```
position:absolute; right: 0;
```

No need for float:right with absolute positioning

And make sure the parent element is set to position:relative;

Answer (score 1):

I deactivated the position absolute so now the login floats right: http://jsfiddle.net/David_Knowles/yxFZ2/

```
#LoginBox {
float : right;
background-color: 
palegreen;
/* position: absolute; */ 
}
```

Adding the `position:relative;` gives a context for `position:absolute` but at the same time overrules the float declaration:

I prefer to use floats over absolute positioning because other elements are able to react to them and adjust accordingly. Absolute positioning normally requires more coding elsewhere in the page and is generally less flexible,